# How traffic is routed in Network when accessing local machine via external ip from local network

Tags: networking, routes, webserver, infrastructure

**Setup Info**

1. A web server running on a machine with ip 192.168.0.2
2. I have a domain example.com mapped to my external ip 76.x.x.x
3. My router has been configured to forward request on port 80 to internal ip 192.168.0.2:80
4. I have a machine called MyMachine connected to router via ethernet
5. Internet Download and Upload Speed 50/5 Mbps

Lets say I have a file of size 10GB in webserver and when i download this file by accessing local ip 192.168.0.2 from MyMachine it downloads at 1Gbps but the same file if i download it via my external ip or my domain example.com from MyMachine it dowmnloads only at 50Mbps which is my Internet download speed.

Can  someone please explain me what is really happening and why my download speed is slow when i use my external ip or domain name to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

Because the file passes by the router to be routed back to your computer. On the local way it's faster because it uses layer 2 and doesn't have to pass through your router but by the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading from a webserver means uploading for the webserver and downloading for the computer you're downloading it on. That's why you are limited to your provider's upload speed